# What's the respawn speed of Lost and Found treasure caches?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm currently looking to yoink a [Blade of the Poisoned Mind](http://www.wowhead.com/object=213972) from one of the several caches for the [Lost and Found](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=7281) Achievement. However, I'm shooting in the dark in my camping as I don't know when it'll show up.

The comments on Wowhead are of very little help, with some merely saying that it might have something to do with server restarts, and others discounting that possibility.

What is the actual respawn window for Lost and Found treasures? A couple of hours? Days? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bit the bullet and camped the *Blade of the Poisoned Mind* spawn point. Since there's only one data point, it's not a conclusive answer, but suffice it to say that the respawn time is *looooooong*.

My camping journal:

- Began camping immediately after Tuesday maintenance ended, starting at 11 am GMT-7.
- Camped continuously until the servers restarted Wednesday morning at 5 am GMT-7. This may have reset the re-spawn timer.
- Restarted camping at 6:20 am GMT-7 until ~2:45 am Thursday, when it finally spawned.

So, given this, the respawn period is at least 20 hours (if the server restart reset the timer) or 35 hours (if it didn't).

Answer (score 0):

Not true. The respawn time is ticked by the other items being found in Pandaria. Similar to the respawn algorithm for the rare creatures in Northrend. The server creates a new item in a different location after a short waiting period. I have farmed most of the objects and noticed that the items will only spawn in a new location once another is found. So your waiting period is dependent on other players.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured that if you just go wait and try to get the other lost treasures and come back to it, it is usually there because of you picking up different lost treasures. The timers are set so when a different lost treasure is picked up the opposite one will spawn. That's what happened with me.